# Applets missing from top panel

Tags: gnome, budgie, widgets

Just installed Dropbox recently, only to have a square with a red x over it appear in the top panel instead of the Dropbox logo. This 'placeholder' isn't even clickable and it goes away if I turn 'AppIndicator Applet' off in Budgie's desktop settings (comes back if i turn it back on). Dropbox still works great otherwise. Having a similar problem with Cortina wallpaper slideshow where instead of displaying a widget in the top panel, an empty space (which just happens to be clickable) appears. Cortina works fine even with the widget not there, but is there any way to fix these two problems though?

Comment: The following information needed: Ubuntu version, desktop manager name (GNOME?),  screenshot.

Comment: Please split this into two separate questions since the issues are different.  For each question please explain from where you installed the software - give the commands you used to install.